# Powershell: Progress Bar for folders being created

Tags: function, powershell, loops

I'm trying to see if I can get a progress bar going based off either the duration of my script or for the folders it is creating.

The script in question is building a framework of a big folder structure. I'd like to incorporate a progress bar into the script. What I have so far is the following:

```
$Progress = @{
    Activity = 'Building Source Folders'
    CurrentOperation = "Verifying/Building"
    PercentComplete = 0
}

Write-Progress @Progress
$u = 0

ForEach ($f in $folders) {
$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\Source -Recurse
$u++
[int]$percentage = ($u / $folders.count)*100
$progress.CurrentOperation = "$f"
$progress.PercentComplete = $percentage

Write-Progress @Progress
}

rest of the script
```

Any help is super appreciated as I don't know if having it as a loop is the only way to do a progress bar or if it's better to do it as a function.

Comment: I don't see any folder being created in your code..

Comment: @Theo I didn't include it as it's just a bunch of ```if ``` statements followed by the ```New-Item``` command to create the folders if they don't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting what I was looking for with this code from https://adamtheautomator.com/building-progress-bar-powershell-scripts/:

````
$steps = ([System.Management.Automation.PsParser]::Tokenize($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition, [ref]$null) | where { $_.Type -eq 'Command' -and $_.Content -eq 'Progress-Bar' }).Count
$StepCounter = 0

function Progress-Bar {
    param(
        [int]$StepNumber,
        [string]$Message,
        [string]$Percent = "$(([math]::Round((($StepCounter)/$steps * 100)))) %"
    )

    Write-Progress -Activity 'Building TDC Source Folder Structure' -Status $Message -CurrentOperation $Percent -PercentComplete (($StepNumber / $steps) * 100)
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have the Get-ChildItem call inside the loop, which doesn't make sense and won't work. Pulling it outside should work:

```
$Progress = @{
    Activity = 'Building Source Folders'
    CurrentOperation = "Verifying/Building"
    PercentComplete = 0
}

Write-Progress @Progress
$u = 0

$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\Source -Recurse

ForEach ($f in $folders) {
    $u++
    [int]$percentage = ($u / $folders.count)*100
    $progress.CurrentOperation = "$f"
    $progress.PercentComplete = $percentage

    Write-Progress @Progress
}
```

And depending how many folders we're talking here, it's worth thinking about the performance impact. Write-Progress is pretty slow.

On my machine, 10,000 Write-Progress calls takes 10 seconds using this code:

```
Measure-Command {
    for( $i = 0; $i -lt 10000; $i++ ) {
        Write-Progress -Activity '' -Status "$i of 10,000" -Id 1 -PercentComplete 0
    }
}
```

One option is to do a check and only do a Write-Progress every so often. This version does it every 100 iterations (so 100 Write-Progress calls), and this code runs in .046 seconds on my machine:

```
Measure-Command {
    for( $i = 0; $i -lt 10000; $i++ ) {
        # Only do a Write-Progress on every 100th loop iteration
        if( $i % 100 -eq 0 )
        {
            Write-Progress -Activity '' -Status "$i of 10,000" -Id 1 -PercentComplete 0
        }
    }
}
```